# How to use ! in edit/replace code in for loop batch

Tags: batch

Im trying to test if a line contains a string of text with a for loop, and then remove that string if it is there.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (test.txt) do (
    echo %%A | findstr /C:"[B]" 1>nul
    if !errorlevel!==1 echo %%A
    if !errorlevel!==0 SOMEHOW REMOVE [B] AND ECHO IT WITHOUT THE B
    )
```

The problem is that the following concept does not work inside a for loop:

```
set var=[B]Hello
set Va2r=%_var:[B]=%
```

And replacing the `%`s with `!`s doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [delayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) when setting **and** using a variable inside a (code block)

This will `eat` exclamation marks in your text.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\26\SU_1334338.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (test.txt) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    Echo=!line:[B]=!   
)
```

**EDIT just to remind that the usage of `for /f` has some pitfalls:**

- Process the following file `test.txt` with the above batch

---

```
This line contains [ B ]   here :[B]:
   this line is indented
there is an empty line following

; this line starts with a ;
:: this is the last line
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SU_1334338.cmd
This line contains [ B ]   here ::
this line is indented
there is an empty line following
:: this is the last line
```

So what happened:

- the replacment of [B] was done, but
- the indentation is lost,
- the empty line vanished
- the line starting with the semicolon also.

There is a difference bewteen using `"delims="` and `"tokens=*"`

- when setting the delimiter to nothing, the whole line is processed unchanged.
- using all tokens (*) does what it sounds like but the default delimiter <kbd>Space</kbd> in front of the first token is removed (or multiple, as they are counted as one) so this explains why the indentation is removed.
- the removal of empty lines is a general behaviour which can be worked around - with numbered lines - see the next batch file
- `for /f` supports one `end of line` characer which by default is the semicolon in the very first column. If this is an issue define an `Eol=` which will most likely not interfere with the text, like a vertical bar `|`

This, not very different batch file avoids the listed pitfalls using find with /V and a most unlikely to occur string in the text and numbers all lines, so they aren't empty for the `for /f`; to remove the number the delimiter is set to `]` what incurs the risk that this char in the first column(s) is also removed.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\26\SU_1334338_2.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1* eol=|delims=]" %%A in  (
    'find /N /V "#+§-*;" ^< test.txt'
) do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (Echo(!line:[B]=!) else Echo(
)
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SU_1334338_2.cmd
This line contains [ B ]   here ::
   this line is indented
there is an empty line following

; this line starts with a ;
:: this is the last line
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work the way I wrote it. I know to always use Setlocal. Your way works great though thank you.

Comment: Couldn't keep me from elaborating on some `for /f` issues.

Comment: Haha it’s appreciated